# Running a script in task scheduler on hyper v startup

Tags: ipv6, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

When my rackspace hyper v server is bought online, I have a scheduled task that is set to run on startup to get the internal ip address and make use of it.

It seems though that the internal ip address of the server changes after I bring the image back online but after startup, as if maybe the machine has an ip configured, then some other event changes it.

Can anyone suggest an event that I can use to get this value a a later step, after the internal ip address has been finalised?

Comment: Wait [time value]?

Answer (score 0):

See https://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection for a method by which you can have a scheduled task run on connectivity changed - which should happen when your IP is set.

Keep in mind, however, that you may not have just one IPv6 address and it may not be constant across the uptime of the server.